# What modifications do I need to make to Marlin if I completely replace the heated bed assembly?

Tags: marlin, heated-bed, firmware, software

I have a 3D printer built from generic, scrap parts.
It's controlled by a 2+ years old `MKS GEN L` board running Marlin version `1.1.x`.

I want to do a complete bed assembly replacement, including:

- Heated bed
- Thermistor
- Y-carriage

All the hardware bits, including the z-endstop are sorted and ready to be installed.

**My question is:**

- Once I replace the assembly, what kind of software / firmware modifications do I need to do to Marlin configuration for my printer to work correctly?

I understand that I need to modify dimensions and offsets but I am unsure what else will I need to change within the codebase before flashing Marlin.

Comment: Hi Phil! Are you looking for general guidelines ("kind of changes") or do you observe some issue? Then you could significantly improve the question by adding information of what does work incorrectly now? Along with information about the previous setup. If only height is different, or other dimensions either? If the previous bed was heated, or it should be enabled now? As for Marlin, there were some vital changes between 1.0 and 1.1 like `TEMP_BED_` settings, so the exact version is also important.

Comment: Hello @octopus8. Thank you for your kind suggestions. I have updated my original question trying to improve it with the details you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Dimensions if they differ, maybe endstop offsets and possibly a different thermistor type.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to PID Autotune the bed as well.